# How to enlarge colored plot of svm model in R (e1071)

Tags: r, svm

I am exploring library e1071 in R for svm classifiers and I have a problem, I cannot find solution for. I am training a linear svm classifier on some dataset. The results are as I have expected, but when I am trying to enlarge plot, it is not filled with color that represents a class. The following plot represents the problem.

[image: Plot of classifier with changed limits]

Since it is a linear classifier, there should be a discriminant function computed and on that basis the whole space can be classified, so that there is no white space on the plot.

Here is how I achieve the results:

```
install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("e1071")
library("readxl")
library("e1071")
data <- read_excel("/path/to/your/file", col_names = FALSE)
X = cbind(data[1], data[2])
X = sapply(X, as.numeric)
y = sapply(data[length(data)], as.numeric)
y = as.factor(y)
train.data = data.frame(X, y)
model <- svm(y ~ ., data = train.data, kernel = "linear")
plot(model, train.data, X__2 ~ X__1, xlim = c(-0.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-0.5, 1.5), fill = TRUE)
```

The data I have used is from: http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset.php?cod=183

In my case in excel file there should be only data, no column desctiption.

In advance, thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably, the model has normalized your data to 0-1 range? There is a note to `svm()`: "Data are scaled internally, usually yielding better results"

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: as @Ekatef note, the data is scaled. YOu don't have information outside 0:1, why not remove `xlim = c(-0.5, 1.5), ylim = c(-0.5, 1.5), fill = TRUE)` and plot `plot(model, train.data)` and let it scale up the 0:1?